# How do you add an HTTP API as a data source to Oracle Business Intelligence Enterprise Edition (OBIEE)?

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee, oracle-bi

Am I able to add an HTTP API endpoint (e.g. Elasticsearch HTTP query) directly as a data source in OBIEE? I can't find any documentation online regarding this.

If this is not a supported feature, what other solutions exist e.g. export API endpoints regularly as flat files and add them as datasources?

Answer (score 2):

OBIEE doesn't support HTTP API endpoints as a datasource. BI Publisher supports SOAP web service calls, but not RESTful ones such as Elasticsearch.

If you want to query Elasticsearch one option to consider is somewhat convoluted but possible - use [ES-Hadoop to expose your Elasticsearch to Hive](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/hive.html), and then connect [OBIEE to Hive](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2015/05/obiee-11-1-1-9-now-supports-hiveserver2-and-impala-datasources/).